# session security in OOP/MVC

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, oop, codeigniter

This question is specifically about how to correctly implement session security in a function/OOP/MVC based environment.

I am familiar with session security in a procedural file - if I have a control_panel.php file that is written procedurally, I can simply check session security at the top of the page, or whenever the logic dictates it would be first loaded.

However, I'm new to OOP/MVC, and my pages are now just a bunch of functions!

Hopefully I do not need to check session security in every function..?

Note that I'm using CodeIgniter2.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<?php

class Main_controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
}

public function index() {
   //$this->load->view(my_view);
   //run some code
}

public function function1() {
   //$this->load->model(my_model);
   // run some code
}

private function function2() {
   //$this->load->view(my_view2);
   //run some code
}
?>
```

And in a procedural php page it'd just look like this:

```
<?php

// check user login
if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && !empty($_SESSION["user"])) {

// all of the code on the page

}
?>
```

Comment: It appears that doing session security checking just at the top of the page for OOP does not work.  I find that if I go to www.mysite.com/Main_controller/function1/ that it just loads up function1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the base controller as `MY_Controller` - and put the check there.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if ( ! isset($_SESSION["user"]) OR (empty($_SESSION["user"]))
        {
            // User not logged in - so send them to the home page
            redirect ("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Then extend the `MY_Controller` for each of your controllers you want "secure", the user wont be able to access any of them unless they are logged in

```
class Main_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view(my_view);
        //run some code
    }

    public function function1()
    {
        //$this->load->model(my_model);
        // run some code
    }
}
```

See here for more info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Note that MY_Controller.php doesn't go in the application/libraries folder but in application/core

Answer (score 0):

There is native [session library in Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). Also several extended libraries. if you search CI community there are lots of types and examples. Make session library autoload form `config/autoload.php` and check for session validation inside your main controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion the above solutions would work for simple login validation. what would occur if you wanted to control the page based on what type of user is logged in and other cases. from my experience extend base classes is always a challenge and base classes should be used for generic & cross cutting concerns. I would recommend implementing a separate class that would handle your validation needs then call these classes where needed e.g

```
public function function1()
{
    if(SessionManager::CheckRights("IsMember"))
    {
        //$this->load->model(my_model);
        // run some code
    }
    else
        ......
 }
```